# INSERT statement for MySQL table

Tags: mysql, insert

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `ID` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Name) VALUES (ID=4,Name='xxx')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES (Name='xxx')
```

The problem is that both INSERT statements produce the entry (4,**0**). Why **0** instead of "xxx"?

UPDATE: Primary key changed.

Comment: You specify a primary key that doesn't even exist (airlineid), so the table create shouldn't even work. Also, you don't need to insert a value when using auto_increment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name) VALUES (4, 'xxx')
```

Comment: Because in your case, as said in paxdiablo's post, you use the column=expresion method, which is not baddly wrote, but which is evaluated as 0 in an INSERT ... VALUES statement. To use the column=expression method, prefer the INSERT ... SET statement.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it would be something like this, instead...

`INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('xxx')`

No need for the `Name=` part, since you've already specified which column you wish to insert into with the first `(Name)` definition.

Answer (score 2):

Because the *expression* `Name='xxx'` is false, hence evaluates as zero.

You use the `column=expression` method use in `on duplicate key update` clauses as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html), not in the "regular" section of inserts. An example of that:

```
insert into mytable (col1,col2) values (1,2)
    on duplicate key update col1 = col1 + 1
```

You should be using the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Name) VALUES (4,'xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that syntax of `Name='xxx'` valid? Never seen it before, i assume it is seeing it as an unquoted literal, trying to convert it to a number and coming up with 0? I'm not sure at all

Try this:

`INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('xxx')`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you should mention the name of the column in the values part. And also because you do not define you primary key correctly (airlineID is not part of the field list)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `ID` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Name) VALUES (4,'xxx')

INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Name) VALUES (4,xxx)
```

For more Info just visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)